# Preventing duplicates inserted when using Observable Angular 2

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, angular2-observables

I have an issue where my array is exponentially growing more and more each time I submit a post. I think it is happening in the second observable as that user object is being updated after each post to update the timestamp for when they last updated a post.

I am trying to check on the inside observable if that post is already in the array to prevent the duplicates from being inserted to the array. For some reason this is not working.

```
 loadPosts(url: string) {
    switch (url) {
        case '/timeline/top':
            this.postsService.subscribeAllPosts(this.selectedArea)
                .subscribe(posts => {
                    let container = new Array<PostContainer>();
                    for (let post of posts) {
                        this.getEquippedItemsForUsername(post.username).subscribe(x => {
                                try {
                                    if (container.indexOf(new PostContainer(post, x[0].equippedItems)) === -1) {
                                        container.push(new PostContainer(post, x[0].equippedItems));
                                    }
                                     console.log( container); // grows exponentially after each submitted post
                                } catch (ex) { }
                            }
                        );
                    }
                    this.postContainers = container; // postContainers is the array that is being looped over in the html.
                });
            break;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that by creating a new `PostContainer` you're creating a new object which is not in `container`, so it will add every `post` in `posts`.

You should instead check that some unique value of `post` does not exist in any item of `container`

Something like:

```
if (container.findIndex((postContainer) => postContainer.id === post.id) === -1) {
    continer.push(new PostContainer(post, x[0].equippedItems));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure whether you are correct about the problem, removing duplicates from your posts would be easy like this:

```
this.postsService.subscribeAllPosts(this.selectedArea)
            .distinct()
            .subscribe(posts => {
                ...
            });
```

Comment: @Fred this is a very good tip, i didn't mention it myself, but it's important to USE the power of the Observables and not reinvent the wheel